# Haskell: How to write a function that produces every combinations of any number of lists passed as argument

Tags: haskell, nested-lists, cartesian-product

So lets say I want a function foo, that takes as argument, any number of lists, and return every combinations of the lists elements.

So for instance, `foo [0,1] [0,1,2]` would return `[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]`

and `foo [0,1] [0,1] [0,1]` would return `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]`

I was thinking of working recursively, and for the second example for instance, having `foo x y = [[a,b]|a <- x, b <- y]`, and essentially call `foo (foo [1,0] [1,0]) [0,1]`

But the problem i have right now is that foo returns a list of a list, so the more arguments i give it, the more nested lists it will have and the recursive calls won't work. Does anyone have any idea on how i can approach such a function?

I think working with foo x y is a good idea, so that i can recursively call it on any number of lists. So if i had ls = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4]]
I would call foo on the first two and then on the next one and so on.

Comment: The accepted answer on the dupe doesn't answer this question, but many of the dupe's other answers touch on cartesian products of n>2 lists.

Answer (score 3):

if you wrap all your inputs in a list `foo==sequence`

e.g.

```
> sequence [[0,1], [0,1,2]]

[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is [`sequenceA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequenceA) or [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:sequence). (The former uses `[a]`'s Applicative instance while the latter uses `[a]`'s Monad instance, but in this case they're identical). Both are defined in terms of `traverse`, but let's define it ourselves:

```
foo = foldr f (pure [])
  where
  f x ys = (:) <$> x <*> ys
```